# javascript not passing value to function, but function still have it

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I can't understand how styleFunction works (I took it from this Openlayers 4 [example](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/geojson.html)):

```
var styleFunction = function(feature) {
    return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: reader.readFeatures(listaMappe[i].geoJSON,projector)
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: styleFunction
});
```

No parameters are passed to it (from vectorLayer), but the value `feature` has a value (I thought it should be empty).

This question come from my need to add another parameter to `styleFunction` so I can pass a value from `listaMappe[i].color`. (I tried to change my code just to `function(feature, color)` and I don't know why, but the value `color` is not empty and it's a real number...)

Comment: `style: styleFunction` does not call the function. It only defines it (or its reference, at least) as being `vectorLayer.style`. When it is called (when creating a `new ol.layer.Vector`), any arguments will be passed to it implicitely.

Comment: Adding arguments to a function your not responsible for calling doesn't really make much sense,.. It might be best if you try and explain what it is your want to do with `color` exactly.

Comment: something like adding parameter color to styleFunction and then: `return color == 'red' ? stylesRed[feature.getGeometry().getType()] : stylesBlue[feature.getGeometry().getType()];`

Comment: The OpenLayers API specifies you supply `ol.layer.Vector` with the name of a function for callback, the format for the function is specified in the API https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.html#.StyleFunction   It works the same way as standard javascript callback functions such as `forEach` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

Answer (score 0):

Functions are passed arguments when they are **called**.

`vectorLayer` isn't calling anything.

`vactorLayer` is a variable holding the return value of `ol.layer.Vector`.

`styleFunction` is passed to `ol.layer.Vector` (which is code you have not included in your question and which, presumably is written by someone else). It is somewhere inside that function where `styleFunction` is called and passed arguments.

Comment: But how to pass it an additional argument?

Comment: Write a new function which calls `styleFunction` and passes it whatever arguments you want. Pass that function to `Vector` instead of `styleFunction` itself … or edit the `Vector` function.

Comment: I give the link of the other code https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/geojson.html So you are saying that styleFunction is fired from here? https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html#getStyleFunction So I suppose that I can't add a parameter to the function...

Comment: @Accollativo — Your first link is to an example of how to call `Vector`. Your second link is to the documentation for `Vector`. Neither is the source code of `Vector`.

Comment: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/layer/Vector.js